# Python Display Sprites

Tags: python, pygame, project

in computing in school we haave to do a project, mines is to make a Space Invaders type game. I am still new to python and keep getting these two errors! I dont know how to fix them, any help would be much appreciated.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/Iain/Desktop/Computing Project/Galaxian.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Iain/Desktop/Computing Project/Galaxian.py", line 32, in <module>
    player = Player()
  File "C:/Users/Iain/Desktop/Computing Project/Galaxian.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images\user1.gif').convert()
pygame.error: No video mode has been set

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my code (Its very messy I know and I am sorry :p)

```
import random
import pygame

# Colours

White = (255, 255, 255)
Black = (0, 0, 0)
Red = (255, 0, 0)
Green = (0, 255, 0)
Blue = (0, 0, 255)
Orange = (255, 255, 0)
Yellow = (0, 255, 255)

# Initialize the game and display
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # type: () -> object

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images\user1.gif').convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speedx = 0

        def update(self):
            self.rectx += self.speedx

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player()

all_sprites.add(player)


pygame.mixer.music.load("C:\Users\Iain\Desktop\Computing Project\Audio\music\soundtrack.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

display_width = 1280
display_height = 720

galaxianDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_heightth))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Background = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Iain\Desktop\Computing Project\images\Background.jpg").convert()
Background = pygame.transform.scale(Background, (1280, 720))

galaxianDisplay.blit(Background, [0, 0])
x = display_width / 2
y = display_height / 2

# Loop

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        print(event)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [.convert()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) needs information about display/window color depth (8-bit, 16-bit, 24-bit or 32-bit)

So first you have to create this display/window using [set_display()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode)

---

**EDIT:** Full code.

It executes `set_mode()` before it executes `background = pygame.image.load(...).convert()` and even `self.image = pygame.image.load(...).convert()`

```
import pygame
import random

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WHITE  = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK  = (  0,   0,   0)
RED    = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN  = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE   = (  0,   0, 255)
ORANGE = (255, 255,   0)
YELLOW = (  0, 255, 255)

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 1280
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 720

FPS = 60

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                                     # <-- empty line for readabelity
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("images\\user1.gif").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed_x = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speed_x

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

# empty

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

# - init -

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
display_rect = display.get_rect()

# - objects -

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player()
player.rect.center = display_rect.center
player.speed_x = 1

all_sprites.add(player)

background = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\Iain\\Desktop\\Computing Project\\images\\Background.jpg").convert()
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

# - other -

pygame.mixer.music.load("C:\\Users\\Iain\\Desktop\\Computing Project\Audio\\music\\soundtrack.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

# - mainloop -

crashed = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not crashed:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        print(event)

    # - updates (without draws) -

    all_sprites.update()

    # - draws (without updates) -

    display.blit(background, (0, 0))

    all_sprites.draw(display)

    pygame.display.update()

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(FPS)

# - end -
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `pygame.display.set_mode` too late. You need to move these lines before you create a new instance of `Player()` as the constructor you have defined is trying to load an image before the display mode has been set.

```
display_width = 1280
display_height = 720

galaxianDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
```

In other words, your code should look like this

```
...

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

display_width = 1280
display_height = 720

galaxianDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))   

player = Player()

all_sprites.add(player)

pygame.mixer.music.load("C:\Users\Iain\Desktop\Computing Project\Audio\music\soundtrack.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

...
```